# Jquery Ajax Post Not Carrying Over Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use Jquery Ajax to submit a simple form but the page looks to reload after I hit submit, the form values are being shown in the url string and the post variables never make it to the php page. It looks like it's being treated as a GET or something.

Form is as follows:

```
<form id = "textform">
Sent To: <input type="tel" name="number" id="name" placeholder="+1 999 999 9999" required>
<br>
<br>
Message:<textarea name="message" form="textform" placeholder="Enter text message here..." required></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Ajax code is as follows:

```
<script>

    $("textform").on("submit",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

         let number = $(this).find("[name='number']").val();
         let message = $(this).find("[name='message']").val();

        $.post('/aws/sendtext.php', { number: number, message : message}),

            function(returnedData){
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = returnedData;

            }).fail(function(){

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Failed";
    });

    });

</script>
```

Not sure why data isn't coming from the form and it still gets treated as a GET.

**UPDATE-Added order of html tags below:**

```
<?php
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form>
</form>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you mind if I provide a different syntax to achieve the same outcome, or would you rather keep using your own approach? I'll stay on topic and use an AJAX method of course.

Comment: Any method would be good, along as it is simple. I like the $.post way cause it looks clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not capturing the form in your jQuery, because you are using `$("textform")` instead of `$("#textform")`. That makes the form submits as default, with a GET method (since you didn't declare it in the `<form>` tag).

So, it would look something like this:

```
$("#textform").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

     let number = $(this).find("[name='number']").val();
     let message = $(this).find("[name='message']").val();

     $.post('/aws/sendtext.php', { number: number, message : message})
        .done(function(returnedData){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = returnedData;
        }).fail(function(){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Failed";
        });

});
```

and it should work properly

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/79t2bem1/8/

Comment: still seeing the parameters in the url and the post response doesn't return anything.

Comment: You have some malformed syntax in your javascript, making it to not capture the jQuery. I'll edit my answer with the corrections

Comment: I pasted your answer, and it is still submitting as a GET.

Comment: Maybe it's a cache thing? I did it on a jsfiddle and it works. I'll put it on my answer

Comment: Could it be where I have the script located in my php file? I have updated my question with order of my tags.

Comment: Probably not. If you can see the HTML then you should execute the js. Do you have any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: Nothing in console.

Comment: I am using PHPStorm for this project and I added JQuery as a framework but for some reason it isn't registering on the server as having JQuery with the project. If I add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` then the POST works....odd